# How to import data into Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I am new to Tensorflow and to implementing deep learning. I have a dataset of images (images of the same object).

I want to train a **Neural Network model** **using python and Tensorflow** for object detection.

I am trying to **import the data** to Tensorflow but I am not sure what is the right way to do it.

Most of the tutorials available online are using public datasets (i.e. MNIST), which importing is straightforward but not helpful in the case where I need to use my own data.

***Is there a procedure or tutorial that i can follow?***

Comment: what does your data look like? add that to the question if you can. but the suggestions in the ans are helpful starting points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to import images for training, you can use Tensorflow but these will be imported as Tensorflow objects, which you won't be able to visualize until you run the session.

My favorite tool to import images is `skimage.io.imread`. The imported images will have the dimension `(width, height, channels)`

Or you can use importing tool from `scipy.misc`.

To *resize* images, you can use `skimage.transform.resize`.

Before training, you will need to **normalize** all the images to have the values between 0 and 1. To do that, you simply divide the images by 255.

The next step is to **one hot encode** your labels to be an array of 0s and 1s.

Then you can build and train your CNN.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to make sure, the vector i will feed to the network should be a matrix of flattened images? (i.e. if i had 500 images of size 10*10 then the vector i need to feed the network with should be 500*100 and all the images need to be in grayscale (i.e. between 0 and 1)

Comment: No you will need to vertically stack them, so they will have the dimensions (batch,10,10,1). Between 0s and 1s is not about grayscale, the channel of 1 is greyscale, and 3 is colored images

Comment: sure sure I meant to rescale between 0-1! but that shape is for a CNN no NN is that correct?

Comment: The (batch,10,10,1) shape you meant? Yea it is for CNN

Answer (score 1):

You could create a data directory containing one subdirectory per image class containing the respective image files and use `flow_from_directory` of [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).

A tutorial on how to use this can be found in the [Keras Blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).